# Flutter UI Components plugin or module

Tags: flutter

i have experience android and IOS and react native also . the best thing that i love react native is allow to create ui native component to bridge to react native . 
is it possible create ui in Kotlin/Java and Swift/Objective-C and bridge to flutter?

Comment: It's pissible, but if you can avoid it, you should. If you want to buikd apps that way, Flutter is probably not what you want. I Flutter widgets are best built in Flutter.

Comment: do you have any link example for build this? 
i try looking for it a whole day but seem not found it.

Comment: Maybe what you want is create a custom Render Object. Which is the equivalent of creating a custom DOM element for web app.

Comment: The best thing that you love about react native actually degrades the performance, imagining you have a huge app with huge number of native widgets. Every time there will be a need to create a bridge to have that native widget.

Comment: yeah it's true xD .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's not possible, or at least shouldn't be done.

Flutter's approach on UI rendering is the opposite of React-Native. React-Native is a binding to OS native components. While Flutter recreated the Material/Cupertino components from scratch.

If you really insist on doing it consider diving into the code of [video_player](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player) 
or map_view plugin. But they are unique